# "My dog could [have] jump very high when he was younger"

Tags: modal-verbs, past-tense

I did a test and made a mistake. I wrote:

> "My dog *could have jumped* very high when he was younger."

The right sentence was:

> "My dog *could jump* very high when he was younger."

When I was making the sentence I was thinking that people usually say "You *could have told* me!", there is some action and it is in the past–the same for the dog. Could you explain me what is wrong?

Comment: The first sentence begs the continuation: _but he didn't because of his short legs..._

Comment: actually Graduate if I had been your teacher I would have complimented you for your attempt to be more adventurous with the language. It is an irony of sorts that the more you study and learn the more mistakes you will make. Upper-intermediate students will write longer, better compositions or answers than the the elementary ones, but they will also tend to make more subtle mistakes. It is part of the process of learning and mastering any skill.

Comment: Question: Is the first sentence grammatically incorrect or wrong context? Shouldn’t you already know/seen that your dog could/couldn’t jump that high since you are talking in the past tense?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The past form of *can* is normally *could* (when you use it in the sense of ability to do something):

> John *can* read. He's four years old.

When talking about the past, you would say

> John *could* read when he was four years old.

When you say that something *could have happened*, it means that it *almost happened*. It *could have happened*, but it *didn't*.

For example,

> *You could have died!*

means it was possible for you to die, but luckily you didn't.

Comment: Quite right; so *My dog could have jumped very high when he was younger* means he could have, but he didn't, while *My dog could jump very high when he was younger* means he could and did do so. :) +1!

Comment: The first could also have meant that the dog could jump high but the speaker *never witnessed it*